# How to delay onload script for overlay

Tags: overlay, onload

I am currently using this code to trigger an overlay:

```
<body onload="toggleOverlay();">
```

How do I delay this for a set time in milliseconds or seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay the execution of toggleOverlay() using setTimeout().

```
onload="setTimeout('toggleOverlay()', 1000);
```

When the page loads, the setTimeout is executed but not yet the toggleOverlay.